# Is is possible to use !Sub to concatinate one environment variable with another in SAM CLI templates for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I have a group of lambdas that I have most of the items within parameter store parameters. I have the sub trees seperated by envrionment.

Example

```
/prod/type/app1/parameter1
/prod/type/app1/parameter2
/prod/type/app2/parameter1
/dev/type/app1/parameter1
/dev/type/app1/parameter2
/dev/type/app2/parameter1
```

I would like to reference the path within the environment variables of a template.yml for a lambda function using SAM CLI.

I am trying to use !Sub but I am not having the results that I was hoping for.

Example:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    ENV: "DEV"
    SSM_PS_APP1_PATH: !Sub "/${ENV}/type/app1/"
```

The Results I get are:

```
/ENV/type/app1
```

My question is it possible to reference another variable within the Environment Variable Declaration using !Sub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, its not possible. You would have to make `ENV` CloudFormation variable as well:

```
Parameters:
  ENV:
   Default: DEV
```

and then:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    ENV: !Ref ENV
    SSM_PS_APP1_PATH: !Sub "/${ENV}/type/app1/"
```